# Need to find a specific string pattern php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to find a specific pattern on a string coming from MySQL table.
I get the results and try to search within with fetch_array if a string begins with this pattern:  CR - and any number (CR62580) for example.

I am not good with regular expression, so I've tried a lot of combinations, but I can't get the right one... can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$num = 'CR62580';
if (preg_match('/^CR\d+/', $num)) {
    // matches pattern!
}
```

I'd suggest http://regular-expressions.info for getting up and running on the basics of regexen.